# I upgraded my jQuery to 1.9.1, but I have issues with a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to edit this script to soothe with the jQuery 1.9.1 standard but it still not working. My code is below

```
$(document).on('each', 'a.delete', function(index, element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
        alert('here');
    });
});
```

It just does not work with no errors in console. But I had it working on 1.3.2 version if I remove the on method.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate the `a.delete` elements? Try `$('a.delete').each(function() {...});`

Comment: I am not recieving any error. It just not working @Anzeo

Comment: I am displaying a list of rows through ajax. and each roles would contain elements a tag with class delete. I want to use a delete icon to be able delete each roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('a.delete').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
        alert('here');
    });
});
```

For simplifying your code

```
$('a.delete').on('click',function() {
     alert('here');
});
```

If they are creating dynamically then try

```
$(document).on('click','a.delete',function() {
     alert('here');
});
```

Comment: It not working. the a.delete element is created on the page through an ajax call. But before it worked with in 1.3.2 then I used the live method

Comment: I dont know why it not working nw. It just frustrating me here

Comment: .live is deprecated. You should start using .on as per the jQuery documentation. There are a lot of issues with .live that are noted in the documentation, and is why it's been replaced with .on.

Comment: Thanks the last script worked. I tried it again and it worked

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop through all the anchor tags, you could just use event delegation by targeting the class of the anchor tag as shown below. This is more efficient, less code and best practise.

```
$('a').on('click','.delete', function() {
    alert('here');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.delete").click(function(){
        alert("here");
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't syntax errors, but your code not works because `each` is not a valid event to be handled from a function; so it will be never fired.

You can use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

and attach a click handler to all the matched elements.

Code:

```
$('a.delete').on('click',function() {
    alert('here');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/67DNx/

Or if your elements are dynamically added you can use event delegation:

> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest,
>   innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur
>   all the way up to the body and the document element. In Internet
>   Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not
>   natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create
>   consistent cross-browser behavior.
>
> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function () {
    alert('here');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/67DNx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have been able to solve this. in a very simple way. Though I got ideas from some post which were not really perfect for me.

```
$(document).on('click','a.delete',function() {
             alert('here');
});
```